# Circles inside circle and vertical centering text

Tags: html, css

I am trying to draw 2 outer circle around a circle and keeping the text as vertically centered.

I am able to draw a circle outside a circle but not the 3rd one.

Html

```
<div id="content">
    <div id="outer-circle">
        <p>text</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

Demo : http://jsfiddle.net/squidraj/7vusbo0v/1/

The text is also not centering horizontally.

Any help is highly appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is my solution, based on your code:

- Creating a "3rd circle" by using the parent `#container`
- centering the text by using the `display:table-cell`(which allows you to `vertical align` elements)

```css
#content {
  border-radius: 50%;
  height: 320px;
  width: 320px;
  position: relative;
  box-shadow: 0 0px 0 10px green;
  margin: 10px;
}
#outer-circle {
  background: #385a94;
  border-radius: 50%;
  height: 300px;
  width: 300px;
  position: absolute;
  box-shadow: 0 0px 0 10px black;
  top: 10px;
  left: 10px;
  display: table;
}
#outer-circle p {
  display: table-cell;
  vertical-align: middle;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div id="content">
  <div id="outer-circle">
    <p>text</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

I was editing my answer by the time it got accepted and received comments on, but no matter what I'm giving the other solution i was typing at the time:

- Applying the `border` property  to your `#outer-circle` would do the "3rd circle" since you are using `box-shadow` on it.
- to vertical align the text, same solution as the 1st one.

```css
#outer-circle {
  background: #385a94;
  border-radius: 50%;
  height: 300px;
  width: 300px;
  position: absolute;
  box-shadow: 0 0px 0 10px green;
  top: 10px;
  left: 10px;
  display: table;
  border: 10px solid black;
  margin:10px;
}
#outer-circle p {
  display: table-cell;
  vertical-align: middle;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div id="content">
  <div id="outer-circle">
    <p>text</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Awesome. I have not even think about main container. Thank you so much for your help.

Comment: Why not use `border` on `outer-circle`?

Comment: @msfoster that was coming as my 2 solution, I was editing at the moment I received the comments, I don't know why I go always for the complicated path then i came across in my mind with easiest solution.

Answer (score 1):

There is nothing different with them being in a circle, so follow the normal [centering rules](https://css-tricks.com/centering-css-complete-guide/)

The specifics are dependant on what browsers you need to support

Comment: Thank you so much for the link. I am using flex :). Do you know how can I draw another border around the circle using single class or i need to specify another div?

Comment: you can use the `border` css property to define a border, rather than overlap two circles.

Answer (score 1):

Patrick's reference is correct. Give the following a try:

```
#outer-circle p { 
 text-align: center; 
 width: 100%;
 position: absolute; 
 top: 50%;
 transform: translateY(-50%);
 margin-top: -5px;
}
```

Note that I've added a negative top margin, which accounts for your border width.

Comment: Thanks a lot. It works. I am trying to create another circle.Is it possible using single div or I have to specify another div?

Comment: Currently you do not use the `border` property, so  you can use it to add another circle.

Answer (score 0):

set you css

```
    #outer-circle p {
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  /* position: absolute; */
  right: 0;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 50% 0;
  top: 0;
}
```

see https://jsfiddle.net/fwzfoncy/